# SELECT within UPDATE gives an error

Tags: oracle

I am getting `SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table` error on this statement:

```
UPDATE 
(
SELECT CELLS.NUM, UND.CLIENT_PARAMS
FROM CELLS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN UND 
ON CELLS.UND_ID = UND.ID
WHERE CELLS.SASE = 1
) t
SET t.CLIENT_PARAMS = 'test';
```

I would like to update `CLIENT_PARAMS` field for all rows, which select returns.

Comment: I'll guess you are getting multiple rows from cells for the same rows because it joins more than once to und.  But, if you would add some DDL and some example data, we could help more.

Comment: Which do you need ? Update all occurrences of UND or update all occurences where the UND.ID matches an UND_ID on the CELLS table with a SASE of 1 ? Or maybe something else entirely ?

Comment: Basically an UPDATE statement is - UPDATE a_table SET some_values WHERE some_records_qualified_by_something. Your statement does not say what you want to update and the qualification on which rows is unclear.

Comment: @BriteSponge: I need update all occurrences of `UND.CLIENT_PARAMS`, where the `UND.ID` matches an `UND_ID` on the `CELLS` table with a `SASE` of 1.

Comment: @BriteSponge: I omitted the `WHERE` part, because I need to update ALL matches, returned by inner SELECT.

Comment: @Pablo - the WHERE clause is there to limit the rows updated based on a condition. Your condition is 'where the row matches a CELLS row'. Therefore you need the WHERE clause to apply your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward (though possibly not the most efficient) way to update rows in one table which correspond directly to rows in another table via an identity column would be to use `WHERE table1.column IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE ...)`.

In this case:

```
UPDATE UND
SET    client_params = 'test'
WHERE  id IN
   (SELECT und_id
    FROM   CELLS
    WHERE  SASE=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE und u
SET    client_params   = 'test'
WHERE  EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
       FROM   cells c 
       WHERE  C.SASE = 1
       AND    c.und_id = u.id)
```

Comment: Possible alternative: `UPDATE und SET client_params = 'test' WHERE id IN (SELECT und_id FROM cells WHERE sase=1)`. Disclaimer: I don't have the means to test this right now, so I'm not 100% certain that it will work (otherwise I'd post it as an answer).

Comment: @Pablo - just to be sure. UND is a table ? Correct ? It isn't a view possibly based on more than one table ?

Comment: @BriteSponge: UND is solid table, not a view. Correct. It has ID as primary key.

Comment: @Quietust: looks like it works, I'll post now final statement

Comment: @Quietust: This works. `UPDATE UND SET UND.client_params = 'test' WHERE UND.id IN (SELECT CELLS.und_id FROM cells WHERE CELLS.sase=1)`. You can post an answer if you wish.

Comment: @Pablo - Im a bit stumped as to why the above doesn't work for you. I have tested on an update here and the update works exactly as I expect.

Comment: @BriteSponge: I will be happy to try more if you have other ideas